# Moving a SVG element in Firefox fails

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

I'm trying to move a box element in a SVG dragging with mouse.
It works fine in Chrome/Chromium but in Firefox works the firsts moves but later fails.
You can test the code in [that site](http://whizzo.tk/nodes/).

Is there any way to make it work in Firefox? Thanks.

The source:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Nodes</title>
        <script>
            'use strict';

            var node;
            var startX;
            var startY;

            function setup() {
                node = document.getElementById('node');
                node.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
                    document.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
                    startX = event.clientX;
                    startY = event.clientY;
                }, false);
                node.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
                    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
                }, false);
            }

            function move(event) {
                var positionX = Number(node.getAttribute('x')) + event.clientX - startX;
                var positionY = Number(node.getAttribute('y')) + event.clientY - startY;
                node.setAttribute('x', positionX);
                node.setAttribute('y', positionY);
                startX = event.clientX;
                startY = event.clientY;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="setup();">
        <svg width="800" height="600">
            <rect width="800" height="600" fill="#444444"/>
            <rect id="node" x="368" y="268" width="64" height="64" rx="8" ry="8" fill="#222244"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S. Sorry about my bad english.

Comment: What does your debugging tell you? Are there any erros? Are the events fired in Fx? Is the desired node available in Fx? Does the `setAttribute()` method works as expected across browsers? Use `console.log()` to help yourself first and try to figure out, which part exactly Firefox has its troubles with.

Comment: Hi, thaks for answer. The code works fine in firefox the first 2-3 moves, then fails, no errors in console, one rect element is moving but other is in origin while dragging, then in unclick, the origin box dissapers and other works fine and need to click again to drop. Sorry for my bad english but is difficult to explain for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event handler for mouse down you must call preventDefault() i.e.

```
  node.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
        startX = event.clientX;
        startY = event.clientY;
    }, false);
```

This should be enough, if it isn't try adding event.preventDefault() calls to the other event handling functions i.e mousemove and mouseup.

Firefox has default handlers for some events and you don't want to use them in this case.

Comment: Thanks! That works great! sorry, I can't vote up, I'm new usser and don't have enought reputation.